# Radio button is not functioning

Tags: asp.net

I'm having problem with my radio button in my gridview. I want to select any row one by one so that I can perform UPDATE, DELETE, and DISPLAY the row. When I select the button, the page will be refreshed and the button I selected before is not selected anymore. So I can't click any menu to update, delete or display the row.  I noticed this is happening when I set the Autopostback = "True".

How can I solve it? Any idea? Below are my codes:

Page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function radiobtn(id) {
var rdBtn = document.getElementById(id);
var List = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
if (List[i].type == "radio" && List[i].id != rdBtn.id) {
List[i].checked = false;
}
}
}
</script>

<asp:RadioButton ID="CheckDel" runat="server" onclick="javascript:radiobtn(this.id)" OnCheckedChanged="CheckDel_CheckedChanged"
AutoPostBack="True" />
```

server end:

```
protected void CheckDel_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
CheckBox chkStatus = (CheckBox)sender;
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chkStatus.NamingContainer;

Session["datestart"] = row.Cells[1].Text;
Session["empid"] = row.Cells[2].Text;
Session["empname"] = row.Cells[3].Text;
Session["days"] = row.Cells[4].Text;
Session["leavetype"] = row.Cells[5].Text;
Session["leavestatus"] = row.Cells[6].Text;

bool status = chkStatus.Checked;

}
```

Comment: First of all icant see any radio button groups here. secondly try to use the event bubbling (use RowCommand of gridview) feature to handle child controls like radiobutton events. Finally stop coding like this try to get an identifier for the event and locate the object in the command event from the grivieews underlying data e.Row.DataItem

Comment: @linodh im new to asp.net. i dont really understand your comment. can u pls explain more?

Comment: set the use radio button group name property appropriately to have the selections to work properly. Ignore second point as radio button cant raise commands.

Answer (score 0):

Do look at the following url  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/adding-a-gridview-column-of-radio-buttons-cs 
Look at section "Using a Literal Control to Inject Radio Button Markup" for more info